# Jquery trigger with click on mobile, hover on desktop

Tags: jquery, css, mobile, resize, window

altough I've seen this question many times I can't really find an answer.
Basically I have a dropdown menu, and I'm trying to add events so that it opens with hover on desktop and with click on mobile devices.

I tried using this code but it works somehow after I resize the window ( it doesn't check immediately, but if I resize the window it does, which is somehow obviously with the given code, but how can I edit it ).

```
    $(window).on('resize', function(event){
    var windowSize = $(window).width(); // Could've done $(this).width()
    if(windowSize < 300){
        $('.menu-button').addClass('bbb');
    } else if(windowSize < 768){
        $('.dd-mlink').click(function() {
            $(this).toggleClass('show');
            $('.dd-nav').toggleClass('dd-nav-full');
            $('.dd-menu').toggleClass('dd-menu-full');
        });
    } else {
        $('.dd-mlink').hover(function() {
            $(this).toggleClass('show');
            $('.dd-nav').toggleClass('dd-nav-full');
            $('.dd-menu').toggleClass('dd-menu-full');
        });
    }
});
```

.dd-mlink is my trigger, it's a vertical full width dropdown so I need more toggleClasses.

Is there any other option? More efficient?
Any libraries that would do the work for me?

I tried lots of way, including creating a div, adding different properties on different sizes (with media queries), and checking those properties, but it doesn't work.
Any help would be much appreciated. Cheers!

Comment: Depending on how your DOM is structured, you could handle all that via CSS, no need for jQuery. But to say more and recommend a best course of action, you'd have to show your DOM.

Answer (score 1):

I actually solve this problem by add on load next to on resize at that window fuction, like this

```
$(window).on('load resize', function(event){
```

here's the code if anyone will ever use

```
$(window).on('load resize', function(event){
    var windowSize = $(window).width(); // Could've done $(this).width()
    if(windowSize < 992){
        // your check here
    } else if(windowSize > 994){
        // other statements
    } 
});
```

You can add as many elses you want.
Cheers. Have a good one